# A comprehensive survey of the types of things in R; 'mode' and 'class' and 'typeof' are insufficient

Tags: r, language-lawyer, r-faq

The language R confuses me. Entities have *modes* and *classes*, but even this is insufficient to fully describe the entity.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/r-types-and-classes-of-variables) says

> In R every 'object' has a mode and a class.

So I did these experiments:

```
> class(3)
[1] "numeric"
> mode(3)
[1] "numeric"
> typeof(3)
[1] "double"
```

Fair enough so far, but then I passed in a vector instead:

```
> mode(c(1,2))
[1] "numeric"
> class(c(1,2))
[1] "numeric"
> typeof(c(1,2))
[1] "double"
```

That doesn't make sense. Surely a vector of integers should have a different class, or different mode, than a single integer? My questions are:

- Does everything in R have (exactly one) *class* ?
- Does everything in R have (exactly one) *mode* ?
- What, if anything, does 'typeof' tell us?
- What other information is needed to fully describe an entity? (Where is the 'vectorness' stored, for example?)

**Update**: Apparently, a literal 3 is just a vector of length 1. There are no scalars. OK But... I tried `mode("string")` and got `"character"`, leading me to think that a string was a vector of characters. But if that was true, then this should be true, but it's not! `c('h','i') == "hi"`

Comment: You haven't passed a list in your example, but a vector. A list would be `list(1,2)` which indeed has `mode`, `class` and `typeof` of `"list"`. If you want to determine if an object has more than one element, you would probably use `length`.

Comment: Also, there are no scalars in R. 3 is actually a vector of length one. So there's no surprise that its the same as your c(1,2) example. You might find [this](http://cran.at.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Basic-types) part of the R language manual helpful.

Comment: Maybe my question is "How would you write a function `serializeme(x)` in R which fully describes everything about `x`"? Would it start off with a test, for the sake of arguments, as to whether `x` is a list or a vector or function name or whatever? What's the 'top-level' test that would be done first?

Comment: Re: your update. A mode of "character" does not mean a single character, but a character variable; other languages might call this a string.  Additionally, just like 3, `"string"` is a length 1 vector of type character.  `c("stringA","stringB")` is a length 2 vector of type character.

Comment: I would probably use `str` or `dput`

Comment: There's no "string" class/mode.  Check the link @joran gave you.  `"hi"` is a 1-length character vector.  If you want a `serializeme` function, could you use... `serialize`?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich is right about `serialize()`, though it's fairly low level.  Depending what you need it for, `save()` might be more to your liking.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, this question is for curiousity, in case I ever try (again) to do some real R work. I don't need a serialize, I just suggested it as an analogy for the sort of understanding I would like.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: sure, but you could look at the source code for `serialize` to see exactly how it works, which would answer your question, right?

Comment: Prior to your comment, I wasn't aware such a function existed :-) I'll look now!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I agree that the type system in R is rather weird. The reason for it being that way is that it has evolved over (a long) time...

Note that you missed one more type-like function, `storage.mode`, and one more class-like function, `oldClass`.

So, `mode` and `storage.mode` are the old-style types (where `storage.mode` is more accurate), and `typeof` is the newer, even more accurate version.

```
mode(3L)                  # numeric
storage.mode(3L)          # integer
storage.mode(`identical`) # function
storage.mode(`if`)        # function
typeof(`identical`)       # closure
typeof(`if`)              # special
```

Then `class` is a whole different story. `class` is mostly just the `class` attribute of an object (that's exactly what `oldClass` returns). But when the class attribute is not set, the `class` function makes up a class from the object type and the dim attribute.

```
oldClass(3L) # NULL
class(3L) # integer
class(structure(3L, dim=1)) # array
class(structure(3L, dim=c(1,1))) # matrix
class(list()) # list
class(structure(list(1), dim=1)) # array
class(structure(list(1), dim=c(1,1))) # matrix
class(structure(list(1), dim=1, class='foo')) # foo
```

Finally, the class can return more than one string, but only if the class attribute is like that. The first string value is then *kind of* the main class, and the following ones are what it inherits from. The made-up classes are always of length 1.

```
# Here "A" inherits from "B", which inherits from "C"
class(structure(1, class=LETTERS[1:3])) # "A" "B" "C"

# an ordered factor:
class(ordered(3:1)) # "ordered" "factor"
```

Comment: What an excellent, lucid explanation.  You've cleared up many mysteries for me with this one answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - Glad you found it useful!

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. Does everything have 'attributes'? It appears that everything does, I was able to do `class(structure(c(1,2), class="list"))` and now it thinks the vector's class is "list"!

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - Yes, all objects can have attributes. And setting the  class attribute to something wrong (like you setting class of a numeric vector to "list"), can lead to errors. But `is.list` would still return `FALSE` because it uses the type information, not the class.

Comment: @Tommy you say that "class makes up a function from the object type". So why `typeof` _double_ corresponds to `class` _numeric_?

Comment: Could u little bit elaborate on "The made-up classes are always of length 1"? In the example you gave, `length(c("B","C"))` is 2!.

Comment: Upvote for this sentence: `mode` [is] the old-style type ... and `typeof` is the newer, even more accurate version. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: If something is weird and broken, it's time to deprecate it.

Answer (score 21):

Here's some code to determine what the four type functions, [class](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/class), [mode](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/mode), [typeof](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/typeof), and [storage.mode](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/storage.mode) return for each of the kinds of R object.

```
library(methods)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(xml2)
library(kable)

setClass("dummy", representation(x="numeric", y="numeric"))

types <- list(
  "logical vector" = logical(),
  "integer vector" = integer(),
  "numeric vector" = numeric(),
  "complex vector" = complex(),
  "character vector" = character(),
  "raw vector" = raw(),
  factor = factor(),
  "logical matrix" = matrix(logical()),
  "numeric matrix" = matrix(numeric()),
  "logical array" = array(logical(8), c(2, 2, 2)),
  "numeric array" = array(numeric(8), c(2, 2, 2)),
  list = list(),
  pairlist = .Options,
  "data frame" = data.frame(),
  "closure function" = identity,
  "builtin function" = `+`,
  "special function" = `if`,
  environment = new.env(),
  null = NULL,
  formula = y ~ x,
  expression = expression(),
  call = call("identity"),
  name = as.name("x"),
  "paren in expression" = expression((1))[[1]],
  "brace in expression" = expression({1})[[1]],
  "S3 lm object" = lm(dist ~ speed, cars),
  "S4 dummy object" = new("dummy", x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)),
  "external pointer" = read_xml("<foo><bar /></foo>")$node
)

type_info <- imap_dfr(
  types,
  function(x, nm)
  {
    tibble(
      "spoken type" = nm,
      class = class(x), 
      typeof = typeof(x),
      mode  = mode(x),
      storage.mode = storage.mode(x)
    )
  }
)

knitr::kable(type_info)
```

Here's the output:

```
|spoken type         |class       |typeof      |mode        |storage.mode |
|:-------------------|:-----------|:-----------|:-----------|:------------|
|logical vector      |logical     |logical     |logical     |logical      |
|integer vector      |integer     |integer     |numeric     |integer      |
|numeric vector      |numeric     |double      |numeric     |double       |
|complex vector      |complex     |complex     |complex     |complex      |
|character vector    |character   |character   |character   |character    |
|raw vector          |raw         |raw         |raw         |raw          |
|factor              |factor      |integer     |numeric     |integer      |
|logical matrix      |matrix      |logical     |logical     |logical      |
|logical matrix      |array       |logical     |logical     |logical      |
|numeric matrix      |matrix      |double      |numeric     |double       |
|numeric matrix      |array       |double      |numeric     |double       |
|logical array       |array       |logical     |logical     |logical      |
|numeric array       |array       |double      |numeric     |double       |
|list                |list        |list        |list        |list         |
|pairlist            |pairlist    |pairlist    |pairlist    |pairlist     |
|data frame          |data.frame  |list        |list        |list         |
|closure function    |function    |closure     |function    |function     |
|builtin function    |function    |builtin     |function    |function     |
|special function    |function    |special     |function    |function     |
|environment         |environment |environment |environment |environment  |
|null                |NULL        |NULL        |NULL        |NULL         |
|formula             |formula     |language    |call        |language     |
|expression          |expression  |expression  |expression  |expression   |
|call                |call        |language    |call        |language     |
|name                |name        |symbol      |name        |symbol       |
|paren in expression |(           |language    |(           |language     |
|brace in expression |{           |language    |call        |language     |
|S3 lm object        |lm          |list        |list        |list         |
|S4 dummy object     |dummy       |S4          |S4          |S4           |
|external pointer    |externalptr |externalptr |externalptr |externalptr  |
```

The types of objects available in R are discussed in the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Basic-types) manual.  There are a few types not mentioned here: you can't test for objects of type "promise", "...", and "ANY", and "bytecode" and "weakref" are only available at the C-level.

The table of available types in the R source is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/35104d51ef86c2572a7efa446f40eec528da3d78/src/main/util.c#L198).

Comment: The first column of the last table is interesting.  Can we say that every object is exactly *one* of those types? My knowledge of R has improved a lot since I first asked this, but I'm still confused about the fundamentals. For example, you gave `list` and `data.frame` as two different items, but now I feel that a data.frame is really just a `list` with a certain `class`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yes, a data frame is just a list, but with extra checking that each element is the same length, and a `row.names` attribute.  And yes, all objects have exactly one of the 20-something possible values of `typeof`.

Comment: Wow... this is like gold here!  It was also educational to me how you were able to create particular syntactic structures.  E.g., `expression({1})[[1]]` is how we can recreate a brace in an expression.

Comment: Why did Hadley Wickham state that "all those answers are wrong" with reference to this table? https://twitter.com/richierocks/status/789380495033376768

Comment: @coder.in.me Because at this point, `mode` and `storage.mode` are legacy features left over from S. You should only ever need to care about `class()` and `typeof()`.

Comment: Shouldn't the spoken type "primitive function" be "builtin function"? I have an objection there. Because: `is.primitive` returns `TRUE` for both special-function and builtin-function. I propose that the spoken type  "primitive function" in the above table to be "builtin function" to reveal the distinction btw builtin-fnc and special-fnc..

Comment: My second objection: spoken type "character vector" should be "string vector". The word character wrongly intutions "1-character string". However, objects with many characters can be in this style: `class(c("ac3","b")) # character`. Note the "ac3". For  `class(c("ac3","b"))`, I have a vector whose components are "strings", not single characters.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER I've changed "primitive" to "builtin" as suggested. I don't agree with your second point: nobody says "string vector". "character vector" is in all the documentation; "string" is more informal.

Comment: I get a different output. In the table provided `class` for every object is of length one. This is not true for many objects, e.g. `class(matrix(logical()))` returns `"matrix"`and `"array"`. That is how I see the table running the code but in the answer it is missing. In the answer it is as if the code were `... class = class(x)[1]...`.

Answer (score 13):

**Does everything in R have (exactly one) class ?**

Exactly one is definitely not right:

```
> x <- 3
> class(x) <- c("hi","low")
> class(x)
[1] "hi"  "low"
```

Everything has (at least one) class.

**Does everything in R have (exactly one) mode ?**

Not certain but I suspect so.

**What, if anything, does 'typeof' tell us?**

`typeof` gives the internal type of an object.  Possible values according to `?typeof` are:

> The vector types "logical", "integer", "double", "complex",
>   "character", "raw" and "list", "NULL", "closure" (function), "special"
>   and "builtin" (basic functions and operators), "environment", "S4"
>   (some S4 objects) and others that are unlikely to be seen at user
>   level ("symbol", "pairlist", "promise", "language", "char", "...",
>   "any", "expression", "externalptr", "bytecode" and "weakref").

`mode` relies on typeof.  From `?mode`:

> Modes have the same set of names as types (see typeof) except that
>   types "integer" and "double" are returned as "numeric".
>   types "special" and "builtin" are returned as "function".
>   type "symbol" is called mode "name".
>   type "language" is returned as "(" or "call".

**What other information is needed to fully describe an entity? (Where is the 'listness' stored, for example?)**

A list has class list:

```
> y <- list(3)
> class(y)
[1] "list"
```

Do you mean vectorization?  `length` should be sufficient for most purposes:

```
> z <- 3
> class(z)
[1] "numeric"
> length(z)
[1] 1
```

Think of `3` as a numeric vector of length 1, rather than as some primitive numeric type.

**Conclusion**

You can get by just fine with `class` and `length`.  By the time you need the other stuff, you likely won't have to ask what they're for :-)

Comment: `attributes` may be handy too.

Comment: As I show in my answer, a `list` with a `dim` attribute is *not* of class "list".

Comment: I didn't realize you could set `dim` on a list.  Oddness.

Answer (score 13):

Adding to one of your sub-questions :

> - What other information is needed to fully describe an entity?

In addition to `class`, `mode`, `typeof`, `attributes`, `str`, and so on, `is()` is also worth noting.

```
is(1)
[1] "numeric" "vector"
```

While useful, it is also unsatisfactory. In this example, `1` is more than just that; it is also atomic, finite, and a double. The following function should show all that an object is according to all available `is.(...)` functions:

```
what.is <- function(x, show.all=FALSE) {

  # set the warn option to -1 to temporarily ignore warnings
  op <- options("warn")
  options(warn = -1)
  on.exit(options(op))

  list.fun <- grep(methods(is), pattern = "<-", invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
  result <- data.frame(test=character(), value=character(), 
                       warning=character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # loop over all "is.(...)" functions and store the results
  for(fun in list.fun) {
    res <- try(eval(call(fun,x)),silent=TRUE)
    if(class(res)=="try-error") {
      next() # ignore tests that yield an error
    } else if (length(res)>1) {
      warn <- "*Applies only to the first element of the provided object"
      value <- paste(res,"*",sep="")
    } else {
      warn <- ""
      value <- res
    }
    result[nrow(result)+1,] <- list(fun, value, warn)
  }

  # sort the results
  result <- result[order(result$value,decreasing = TRUE),]
  rownames(result) <- NULL

  if(show.all)
    return(result)
  else
    return(result[which(result$value=="TRUE"),])
}
```

So now we get a more complete picture:

```
> what.is(1)
        test value warning
1  is.atomic  TRUE        
2  is.double  TRUE        
3  is.finite  TRUE        
4 is.numeric  TRUE        
5  is.vector  TRUE 

> what.is(CO2)
           test value warning
1 is.data.frame  TRUE        
2       is.list  TRUE        
3     is.object  TRUE        
4  is.recursive  TRUE
```

You also get more information with the argument `show.all=TRUE`. I am not pasting any example here as the results are over 50 lines long.

Finally, this is meant as a complementary source of information, not as a replacement for any of the other functions mentionned earlier.

**EDIT**

To include even more "is" functions, as per @Erdogan's comment, you could add this bit to the function:

```
  # right after 
  # list.fun <- grep(methods(is), pattern = "<-", invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
  list.fun.2 <- character()

  packs <- c('base', 'utils', 'methods') # include more packages if needed

  for (pkg in packs) {
    library(pkg, character.only = TRUE)
    objects <- grep("^is.+\\w$", ls(envir = as.environment(paste('package', pkg, sep = ':'))),
                    value = TRUE)
    objects <- grep("<-", objects, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
    if (length(objects) > 0) 
      list.fun.2 <- append(list.fun.2, objects[sapply(objects, function(x) class(eval(parse(text = x))) == "function")])
  }

  list.fun <- union(list.fun.1, list.fun.2)  

  # ...and continue with the rest
  result <- data.frame(test=character(), value=character(), 
                       warning=character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  # and so on...
```

Comment: I included this function (with a few added features) in my package [summarytools](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools). Make sure to use `devtools::install_github(dcomtois/summarytools)` to get the most up-to-date version. The function also uses the functions mentionned in the other answers (mode, class, typeof, attributes, among others) to summarize as much as possible what really __is__ an object.

Comment: Very nice approach. There are 55 `is...` functions in my R version. That said, what will be crema on your code is adding other `is..` functions. For example, `isS4` is not among the 55 `grep(methods(is), ...)` bacause 55 functions has the naming `isPOINTname` whereas in `isS4`, there is no "." in fnc name; i.e. it is not `is.S4`. Can you catch, Dominic, the `is...` functions that violates isPOINTname naming?

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER Pls see my Edit at the bottom... Including all packages would be much more complicated, but having only a few makes good sense!

Answer (score 0):

This question deals with the confusion around all kinds of "types" in R. After reading this and quite a few other sites, in my opinion one comment by @RichieCotton best solves the confusion. It took me quite a while to encounter this comment and I want to highlight it by adding it as an answer.

**[...] at this point, `mode` and `storage.mode` are legacy features left over from S. You should only ever need to care about `class()` and `typeof()`.**

So while reading other answers keep this in mind and focus on `typeof` and `class`. Unfortunately, in other posts it does not become obvious that `mode` and `storage.mode` should not be used. It would have saved me a lot of time reading this comment first.