# Determine the data types of a data frame's columns

Tags: r, dataframe, types

I'm using R and have loaded data into a dataframe using `read.csv()`. How do I determine the data type of each column in the data frame?

Comment: Programmatically (e.g. `sapply(..., class))` or interactively (e.g. `str(...)`) or both? It's generally more scalable to do it programmatically, then you can arbitrarily `Filter(...)` the list for integers, characters, factors etc. Or you can use `grep/grepl` to infer column-types from `names(...)` if they follow any naming conventions

Comment: @smci: I didn't ask for 'programmatically' in my original question. I don't know why you would change the entire nature of my question.

Comment: ok, it was rolled back. It didn't change the entire nature, it clarified it in one of two directions. Interactive approaches using `str(...)` are not scalable and run out of steam on <100 cols.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Your best bet to start is to use [`?str()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/str.html).  To explore some examples, let's make some data:

```
set.seed(3221)  # this makes the example exactly reproducible
my.data <- data.frame(y=rnorm(5), 
                      x1=c(1:5), 
                      x2=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                      X3=letters[1:5])
```

@Wilmer E Henao H's solution is very streamlined:

```
sapply(my.data, class)
        y        x1        x2        X3 
"numeric" "integer" "logical"  "factor"
```

Using `str()` gets you that information plus extra goodies (such as the levels of your factors and the first few values of each variable):

```
str(my.data)
'data.frame':  5 obs. of  4 variables:
$ y : num  1.03 1.599 -0.818 0.872 -2.682
$ x1: int  1 2 3 4 5
$ x2: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
$ X3: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

@Gavin Simpson's approach is also streamlined, but provides slightly different information than `class()`:

```
sapply(my.data, typeof)
       y        x1        x2        X3 
"double" "integer" "logical" "integer"
```

For more information about `class`, `typeof`, and the middle child, `mode`, see this excellent SO thread: [A comprehensive survey of the types of things in R. 'mode' and 'class' and 'typeof' are insufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855589/1217536).

Comment: After using R for several months, I've found that `str(dataframe)` is the fastest way to determine the column types at a glance. The other approaches require more keystrokes and do not show as much information, but they are helpful if the column data types are an input to other functions.

Comment: Hi when I did the same with apply instead of apply, it didn't work

Comment: @DomJo, why would you use `apply()`? That's for matrices. A data frame is a (special kind of) list.

Comment: Because `sapply(foo, typeof)` returns "integer" for Date objects, I used `sapply(foo, class)`. However, this can return a list. So finally I used `names(foo)[sapply(sapply(foo, class), function(x) { "Date" %in% x })]` to identify all columns in `foo` that are a member of class "Date".

Answer (score 72):

```
sapply(yourdataframe, class)
```

Where yourdataframe is the name of the data frame you're using

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest

```
sapply(foo, typeof)
```

if you need the actual types of the vectors in the data frame. `class()` is somewhat of a different beast.

If you don't need to get this information as a vector (i.e. you don't need it to do something else programmatically later), just use `str(foo)`.

In both cases `foo` would be replaced with the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 13):

**For small data frames:**

```
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(mtcars)
```

gives you a print out of the df with data types

```
# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
 * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
```

**For large data frames:**

```
glimpse(mtcars)
```

gives you a structured view of data types:

```
Observations: 32
Variables: 11
$ mpg  <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17....
$ cyl  <dbl> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, ...
$ disp <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167.6...
$ hp   <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215...
$ drat <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 3.0...
$ wt   <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.440, 3.440...
$ qsec <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18.30, 18.90...
$ vs   <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ am   <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ gear <dbl> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...
$ carb <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, ...
```

**To get a list of the columns' data type (as said by @Alexandre above):**

```
map(mtcars, class)
```

gives a list of data types:

```
$mpg
[1] "numeric"

$cyl
[1] "numeric"

$disp
[1] "numeric"

$hp
[1] "numeric"
```

**To change data type of a column:**

```
library(hablar)

mtcars %>% 
  convert(chr(mpg, am),
          int(carb))
```

converts columns `mpg` and `am` to character and the column `carb` to integer:

```
# A tibble: 32 x 11
   mpg     cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs am     gear  carb
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <int>
 1 21        6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0 1         4     4
 2 21        6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0 1         4     4
 3 22.8      4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1 1         4     1
 4 21.4      6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1 0         3     1
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply pass your data frame into the following function:

```
data_types <- function(frame) {
  res <- lapply(frame, class)
  res_frame <- data.frame(unlist(res))
  barplot(table(res_frame), main="Data Types", col="steelblue", ylab="Number of Features")
}
```

to produce a plot of all data types in your data frame. For the **iris** dataset we get the following:

```
data_types(iris)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another option is using the map function of the purrr package.

```
library(purrr)
map(df,class)
```

Answer (score 4):

For a convenient dataframe, here's a simple function in base

```
col_classes <- function(df) {
  data.frame(
  variable = names(df),
  class = unname(sapply(df, class))
  )
}
col_classes(my.data)
  variable     class
1        y   numeric
2       x1   integer
3       x2   logical
4       X3 character
```

Answer (score 3):

Since it wasn't stated clearly, I just add this:

I was looking for a way to create a **table** which holds the **number of occurrences of all the data types**.

Say we have a `data.frame` with two numeric and one logical column

```
dta <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), 
                  b = c(4,5,6), 
                  c = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

You can summarize the number of columns of each data type with that

```
table(unlist(lapply(dta, class)))
# logical numeric 
#       1       2
```

This comes extremely handy, if you have a lot of columns and want to get a quick overview.

*To give credit:* This solution was inspired by [the answer of @Cybernetic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353652/3250126).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that is part of the [helpRFunctions](https://github.com/adam-m-mcelhinney/helpRFunctions) package that will return a list of all of the various data types in your data frame, as well as the specific variable names associated with that type.

```
install.package('devtools') # Only needed if you dont have this installed.
library(devtools)
install_github('adam-m-mcelhinney/helpRFunctions')
library(helpRFunctions)
my.data <- data.frame(y=rnorm(5), 
                  x1=c(1:5), 
                  x2=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                  X3=letters[1:5])
t <- list.df.var.types(my.data)
t$factor
t$integer
t$logical
t$numeric
```

You could then do something like `var(my.data[t$numeric])`.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Worth noting that under the hood this is `lapply(your_data, class)` with a bit of extra processing for formatting.

Answer (score 2):

If you import the csv file as a data.frame (and not matrix), you can also use `summary.default`

```
summary.default(mtcars)

     Length Class  Mode   
mpg  32     -none- numeric
cyl  32     -none- numeric
disp 32     -none- numeric
hp   32     -none- numeric
drat 32     -none- numeric
wt   32     -none- numeric
qsec 32     -none- numeric
vs   32     -none- numeric
am   32     -none- numeric
gear 32     -none- numeric
carb 32     -none- numeric
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a nice Tibble with types and classes:

```
  purrr::map2_df(mtcars,names(mtcars), ~ {
    tibble(
      field = .y,
      type = typeof(.x),
      class_1 = class(.x)[1],
      class_2 = class(.x)[2]
    )
    })
```