# Difference between apply and sapply for data frame columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, sapply

Could someone please explain the differences between how `apply()` and `sapply()` operate on the *columns* of a data frame?

For example, when attempting to find the class of each column in a data frame, my first inclination is to use `apply` on the columns:

```
> apply(iris, 2, class)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
 "character"  "character"  "character"  "character"  "character"
```

This is not correct, however, as some of the columns are numeric:

```
> class(iris$Petal.Length)
[1] "numeric"
```

A quick search on Google turned up [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125298/554531) for the problem which uses `sapply` instead of `apply`:

```
> sapply(iris, class)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
   "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

In this case, `sapply` is implicitly converting `iris` to a list, and then applying the function to each entry in the list, e.g.:

```
> class(as.list(iris)$Petal.Length)
[1] "numeric"
```

What I'm still unclear about is why my original attempt using `apply` didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As often seems to be the case, I figured out the answer to my question in process of writing it up. Posting the answer here in case anyone else has the same question.

Taking a closer look at `?apply` states:

> If ‘X’ is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null ‘dim’
>   value (such as a data frame), ‘apply’ attempts to coerce it to an
>   array via ‘as.matrix’ if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or
>   via ‘as.array’.

So just like `sapply` casts the data frame to a `list` before operating on it, `apply` casts the data frame to a `matrix`. Since matrices cannot have mixed types and there is at least one column with non-numeric data (`Species`), then everything becomes character data:

```
> class(as.matrix(iris)[,'Petal.Length'])
[1] "character"
```