# Get column indexes of class character/integer or any type I define?

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a dataframe, I want to get column indexes (1,4,55,33..) of columns of type integer.

Given df:

```
col1           col2
<character>    <integer>
a              1 
a              2  
vb             3
```

I want to get col1 as character column.

I am trying to do this using:

```
which(sapply(df, function(x) class(x) == "character") == TRUE)
```

Please advise.

Comment: This should do it, `which(sapply(df, class) == 'integer')`

Comment: The `== TRUE` is not needed since the inner "==" already created a logical vector. I suspect the `which` is not needed either, but unless you show your use case we cannot know for sure, Almost any function that accepts numeric arguments for column selection will also accept a logical vector. There is a probability approaching unity that this question has been asked multiple times in the past on SO.

Comment: You could also do stuff like `grep("ch", sapply(df, class))` or `grep("in", sapply(df, class))` if you are lazy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine the data types of a data frame's columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125222/determine-the-data-types-of-a-data-frames-columns)

Comment: ^ It's not an exact duplicate, since they aren't asking for the index, but once you have a list it's just `which(classes == 'integer')`

Comment: Or maybe cleaner `which(sapply(df, inherits, 'integer'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `match`. The second part of this answer is admittedly overly complicating things.

Purely base R:

```
 match(names(Filter(is.numeric,df)),names(df))#speed limitations
 #[1] 2
```

Using Packages:

```
library(dplyr)
    df1<-df %>% 
      purrr::select_if(is.numeric)

     match(names(df1),names(df))
    #[1] 2
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "col1           col2
 a              1 
a              2  
vb             3", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, Filter(is.numeric, df) checks which column in df is numeric and returns logical vector? This vector is the input for the names functions.

Comment: `Filter(is.numeric,df)` gets all numeric columns. We then get the names of those columns and `match` them to the original names.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
which(sapply(df, function(x) is.numeric(x)))

col2 
   2 

which(sapply(df, function(x) is.character(x)))

col1 
   1
```

Or as @David Arenburg suggested:

```
which(sapply(df, is.character))

col1 
   1
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "col1           col2
 a              1 
a              2  
vb             3", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @David Arenburg updated the post. Thanks for your remark.