# How to compare data types of objects in columns across multiple data frames in R

Tags: r

I have 15  different data frames with same number of columns and column names. But some of these columns are indicated to be of different data types. Without checking manually is there a method to detect the data type of the columns that does not share the same data type?

Comment: Please share reproducible example using `dput()` function

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125222/determine-the-data-types-of-a-data-frames-columns) shows you how to get the data types of columns in a single data frame.  So put your data frames in a list (if they aren't already) and `lapply` the solution, then do your comparisons.

Comment: `str(df)` gives you the data type of all columns in data.frame `df`, you can print this in a loop.