# r list, self-created is different from loaded

Tags: r, list

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/association-rules).  From which you can downloaded [this data file](http://www.rdatamining.com/data/titanic.raw.rdata?attredirects=0&d=1) (452 bytes only).

I explored the data structure of the data:

[image: a busy cat]

And then I tried to create the same type of data:

[image: a busy cat]

I have tried feeding in my own list but it didn't work the same way as the `titanic.raw` dataset. I Googled list and all of them look like my list but not like `titanic.raw`.  They are both lists, I used `is.list()` to check.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is you're asking. Are you trying to create a data frame (which also shows typeof() as "list")

Comment: oh, sorry, i am trying to produce the same kind of data like titanic.raw. titanic.raw is a list, so i tried creating my own list using list() but the end result is not the same as titanic.raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confusion that is centered around the distinction between `typeof()` and `class()` in R.  What you have is a *data.frame*, but `typeof()` will show "list".  Consider:

```
> tr <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=letters[1:5])
> typeof(tr)
[1] "list"
> is.list(tr)
[1] TRUE
> class(tr)
[1] "data.frame"
> is.data.frame(tr)
[1] TRUE
> head(tr)
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e
> tl <- list(a=1:5, b=letters[1:5])
> tl
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

> typeof(tl)
[1] "list"
> is.list(tl)
[1] TRUE
> class(tl)
[1] "list"
> is.data.frame(tl)
[1] FALSE
```

For more information about `class`, `typeof`, and `mode` (another related function), see this excellent SO thread: [A comprehensive survey of the types of things in R. 'mode' and 'class' and 'typeof' are insufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855589/a-comprehensive-survey-of-the-types-of-things-in-r-mode-and-class-and-type)

Comment: You're welcome, @FailedMathematician. Try reading the linked thread to learn more.