# Retrieving variable names for numeric variables

Tags: r

I need to run through a large data frame and extract a vector with the name of the variables that are numeric type.

I've got stuck in my code, perhaps someone could point me to a solution.

This is how far I have got:

```
numericVarNames <- function(df) {
    numeric_vars<-c()
    for (i in colnames(df)) {
        if (is.numeric(df[i])) {
            numeric_vars <- c(numeric_vars, colnames(df)[i])
            message(numeric_vars[i])
        }
    }
    return(numeric_vars)
}
```

To run it:

```
teste <-numericVarNames(semWellComb)
```

The is.numeric assertion is not working. There is something wrong with my syntax for catching the type of each column. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than a looping function, how about

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),
                 b = c("a","b","c"),
                 c = c(4,5,6))


## names(df)[sapply(df, class) == "numeric"]
## updated to be 'safer'
names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]
[1] "a" "c"
## As variables can have multiple classes
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855589/5977215) is worth a read

Comment: You turned 10 lines into one! That is extremely useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Luís - no problem. Just be careful with whether you want `numeric` / `integer`, and understand the differences between `class`, `typeof` etc.

Comment: Good answer. You could do: `names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]`

Comment: @Gopala - Thanks, a good improvement. It's important to understand the distinction between `class`, `type*` etc. and how they are used.

Answer (score 1):

Without test data it is hard to be sure, but it looks like there is just a "grammar" issue in your code.

You wrote:

```
            numeric_vars <- c(numeric_vars, colnames(df)[i])
```

The way to get the column name into the concatenated list is to include the whole referred to subset in the parentheses:

```
        numeric_vars <- c(numeric_vars, colnames(df[i]))
```

Try running it with that one change and see what you get.