# Why is `select_if(., is_double)` returning dates?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

When using [`is_double`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/type-predicates.html) with `select_if`, the return value includes columns of lubridate's `date` data type.  Why is this?

Here is a simple example using the `today()` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

mtcars %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% # Convert to tibble
    mutate(today = today()) %>% # Create a date column
    select_if(is_double) # Select double columns
```

---

### Output:

```
# A tibble: 32 x 12
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb today     
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 2020-06-25
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 2020-06-25
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 2020-06-25
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 2020-06-25
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2 2020-06-25
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1 2020-06-25
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4 2020-06-25
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2 2020-06-25
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2 2020-06-25
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4 2020-06-25
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Hopefully I'm missing something simple, are dates recognized as type double?

Comment: Related: [Why is Date is being returned as type 'double'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458989/why-is-as-date-is-being-returned-as-type-double)

Comment: Thank you, it is a pity I couldn't find this prior to asking.  This would have cleared everything up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, `date` is internally stored as `double`

```
typeof(today())
#[1] "double"
```

though its `class` is 'Date'

```
class(today())
#[1] "Date"
```

---

An option is to add another condition in `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
     as_tibble %>%
     mutate(today = today()) %>% 
     select_if(~ is_double(.) && !inherits(., "Date"))
# A tibble: 32 x 10
#     mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21    160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2  21    160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  22.8  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
# 4  21.4  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
# 5  18.7  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
# 6  18.1  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
# 7  14.3  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
# 8  24.4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
# 9  22.8  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#10  19.2  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

In the `dplyr` 1.0.0, we can also use `where` with `select`

```
mtcars %>% 
   as_tibble %>% 
   mutate(today = today()) %>%
   select(where(~is_double(.) && !inherits(., "Date")))
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer!  I ended up using `is.numeric` to achieve the same result.  Is this bad practice at all?

Comment: @MokeEire It is working with the current version of `dplyr`.  Though, can't say whether it becomes a bug in the future release

Comment: select_if(~ is_double(.) && !inherits(., "Date") && !inherits(., "POSIXct")) also exludes dttm