# How does R decide on the mode of a vector?

Tags: r

I'd started learning R recently and in one of the practice questions, this was asked

> What will be the output of `mode(c(12, 45, "30", 34*56))`

Now, since the `numeric` data was in majority, I thought the answer would be `numeric`. But the given answer (which I'd later verified in R console) was `character`.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: *numeric* can always coerced to *character*.

Comment: run ``debugonce(mode)`` and ``mode(c(12, 45, "30", 34*56))`` again for playing with the internals, hence the *why*.

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

Comment: @Nutle I'm new to R, basically coding and I really didn't understand what was happening there

Comment: @JohnCleaver so it's a useful tool to learn then! You basically enter a debug mode, where you can see the internal code of the function, can run and evaluate the code line by line and see how does the result change. Here, for example, you can try ``is.expression(x)``, ``is.call(x)``, etc, and understand which part will be executed by the ``mode`` function in the end. Finally, just type ``x`` and see how does your input look like, when passed to mode.

Comment: Related, (possible duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855589/a-comprehensive-survey-of-the-types-of-things-in-r-mode-and-class-and-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R has a hierarchy of returning the mode.

As given in the documentation for `mode`, (`?mode` to open its documentation)

> "logical", "integer", "double", "complex", "raw", "character", "list", "expression", "name", "symbol" and "function"

gives the way how R returns the mode.

Here, if the vector has even one `function`, the mode is `function`. If there is no `function` present, R checks for `symbol` and so on.