# 2 numbers in R not equal despite being the same, fails in left_join

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a strange problem, when trying to do a `left_join` from `dplyr` between two data frames say `table_a` and `table_b` which have the column `C` in common I get lots of `NA`s except for when the values are zero in both even though the values in the rows match more often.

One thing I did notice was that the `C` column in `table_b` on which I would like to match, has values 0 as `0.0` whereas in the `table_a`, 0 is displayed as simply `0`.

A sample is here

`head(table_a)` gives

```
  likelihood_ols LR_statistic_ols decision_ols   C
1       -1.51591          0.20246            0 -10
2       -1.51591          0.07724            0  -9
3       -1.51591          0.00918            0  -8
4       -1.51591          0.00924            0  -7
5       -1.51591          0.08834            0  -6
6       -1.51591          0.25694            0  -5
```

and the other one is here

`head(table_b)`

```
quantile    C pctile
1  2.96406  0.0     90
2  4.12252  0.0     95
3  6.90776  0.0     99
4  2.78129 -1.8     90
5  3.92385 -1.8     95
6  6.77284 -1.8     99
```

Now, there are definitely overlaps between the C columns but only the zeroes are found, which is confusing.

When I subset the unique values in the `C` columns according to
`a <- sort(unique(table_a$C))` and `b <- sort(unique(table_b$C))` I get the following confusing output:

```
> a[2]
[1] -9
> b[56]
[1] -9
> a[2]==b[56]
[1] FALSE
```

What is going on here? I am reading in the values using `read.csv` and the csvs are generated once on CentOS and once RedHat/Fedora if that plays a role at all. I have tried forcing them to be tibbles or first as characters then numerics and also checked all of R's classes and also checked the types discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855589/a-comprehensive-survey-of-the-types-of-things-in-r-mode-and-class-and-type) but to no avail and they all match.

What else could make them different and how do I tell R that they are so I can run my merge function?

Comment: Would floating point arithmetic be a concern here? If so, how could I build a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Just because two floating point numbers print out the same doesn't mean they are identical.

A simple enough solution is to round, e.g.:

```
table_a$new_a_likelihood_ols <- signif(table_a$likelihood_ols, 6)
```