# What is the difference between is.vector() and is.numeric() functions?

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I'm new to R and I'm wondering if someone can explain the difference between `is.vector()` and `is.numeric()`.

Comment: `v1 <- letters[1:3]` returns TRUE with `is.vector(v1)` and FALSE for `is.numeric(v1)`

Comment: The first tests if an R object is a vector, while the second one tests in an R object is a numeric vector (i.e., the class of that vector)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A comprehensive survey of the types of things in R; 'mode' and 'class' and 'typeof' are insufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855589/a-comprehensive-survey-of-the-types-of-things-in-r-mode-and-class-and-type)

Answer (score 1):

`is.numeric` is a general test to check whether a vector is numeric or not. It will return `TRUE` only if the object passed to it is a vector and consists of only numeric data.
Whereas, `is.vector` tests whether the object is a vector or not. It will return `TRUE` if the object passed is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

`is.numeric` returns true if the base type of the class is `double` or `integer` and when values can reasonably be regarded as numeric. (they should be eligible for arithmetic operations and comparable by their base class)

For any values enclosed in a vector being numeric, (integer and floating-point/decimal values) `is.numeric` triggers as `TRUE`.

Whereas `is.vector` checks the class of your object, whether it falls under the conditions of being a vector. Vectors include different variants pertaining to the type of its contents, which can be `numeric` (strictly numbers inclusive of decimal values) or `character` or logical (having boolean values `TRUE` or `FALSE`) or the vector can be raw or complex as well. (You can check the type of vector using `typeof()` function)

The distinction is clear as for character values or boolean values in your vector, `is.numeric` would return `FALSE` as opposed to a `TRUE` for `is.vector`.

If you were to test the same for data frames instead of vectors, the question would arise between `isNumeric` and `is.data.frame`.