# Why does class() return not the same inside Map()?

Tags: r, function, class, mapping

Reading about R types I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171527/11359310) answer where `class()` is used inside of `Map`. Now I wonder why `class()` returns something else if used inside `Map()`. See here:

```
# Using class() without Map()
> class(matrix())
[1] "matrix" "array"

# Using class() within Map()
Map(function(x){class(x)}, matrix())
[[1]]
[1] "logical"
```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

Inferred from comment and answer: To obtain the expected, i.e. same output, we need to use

```
Map(function(x){class(x)}, list(matrix()))
[[1]]
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear. `Map` is just a wrapper for `mapply`. `mapply` accepts vectors or lists as input for the ellipses argument. Thus, the dimension attribute of the matrix is not preserved. You are seeing the same result as from `m <- matrix(); dim(m) <- NULL; class(m)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply (map) all elements of an empty matrix to a function returning it's class. The class of an empty thing is `NA`. A vector only containing NAs is of class logical in R.