# Frequency cross-tabulation in R for categorical variables

Tags: r

I have a table with over 200 categorical variables. Sample:

```
Cat1 Cat2 Cat3
A B A
B A A
A C A
A B A
```

I want to get frequencies (number of times) any category appeared in the dataset. Something like this:

- A 8
- B 3
  ..

I very new to R and tried using a for loop to get the result. I am sure that there are better ways to do so. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Is `"A"` in `Cat1` the same as `"A"` in `Cat2`, eg? Ie, do you want to count `"A"`s within each variable, or over all variables?

Comment: Thank you for editing. Yes please migrate it.

Comment: Yes "A" in cat1 is same as "A" in other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the most convenient function to count how many tokens you have of each type is [?table](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html):

```
d <- read.table(text="Cat1 Cat2 Cat3
A B A
B A A
A C A
A B A", header=T)
table(d$Cat1)
# A B 
# 3 1
```

The most convenient way to execute `table()` for every categorical variable in a dataset is to use [?summary.data.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/summary.html):

```
summary(d)
#  Cat1  Cat2  Cat3 
#  A:3   A:1   A:4  
#  B:1   B:2        
#        C:1
```

On the other hand, if you want to get a table that collapses over all categorical variables, you can use `table()` with [?unlist](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unlist.html):

```
table(unlist(d))
# A B C 
# 8 3 1
```

To understand what's happening there, the thing to realize is that in `R` a data frame is a special kind of list: each variable is a vector and the data frame is a list of vectors of equal length (cf., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316581/1217536)).  The `unlist()` function turns those into one long vector concatenated from first to last.  Note that if you have some non-categorical variables mixed in, you will need to exclude those with something like `table(unlist(d[,c(<variables to use>)]))`.