# Read a CSV in R as a data.frame

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I am new to R and trying to read a csv. The documentation shows a function `read.csv()`. However, when I read the file and check the type of the variable it shows a list. Documentation shows it as a `data.frame`. Can someone explain why it happens that way?

My code so far:

```
mytable<-read.csv(InputFile,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dim(mytable)
typeof(mytable)
```

Output:

```
dim(mytable)
[1] 500  20

typeof(mytable)
[1] "list"
```

Comment: Nothing unexpected there.  A data frame is a list, just in a different "form".  Look at `class(mytable)` and `is.data.frame(mytable)` and read `?data.frame`

Comment: data.frame is a class - not a type.  Try `class(mytable)` ,

Comment: Thanks, class(mytable) shows it as a dataframe.

Comment: also, I like `str` command a lot, it will show you a concise summary of  your object.

Answer (score 2):

As it is explained in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258536/8900683.
In `R` every "object" has a `mode` and a `class`. The former represents how an object is stored in memory (*numeric*, *character*, *list* and *function*) while the later represents its abstract type.

For example:

```
d <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2))
class(d)
# [1] "data.frame"
mode(d)
# [1] "list"
typeof(d)
# list
```