# R: Determine type of expression

Tags: r, types

how can i determine type of variable in R?

```
t <- seq(from=0, to=10, by=2)
p <- 2
```

*t* and *p* are both: *is.numeric*, *is.atomic*, *is.vector*, not *is.list*, *typeof double*, *class numeric*.

How to determine that *p* is just only a number and that *t* is something more?

Comment: You want to find that `p` is numeric and `t` is a vector of numeric?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/r-types-and-classes-of-variables?rq=1

Comment: @Benjamin Good reference but I am not sure that helps here: `class`, `mode` and `typeof` return always the same value for `t` and `p`.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to know that there is no "scalar" data type in R. Everything is a vector, and "single numbers" are also stored internally as a vector of length one. So `p` and `t` really are the same type of thing, they differ only in length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know the class of an object in R:

```
class(t)
class(p)
```

These 2 objects share the same class `numeric` (they are actually both vectors of numerics, even p is a vector of length 1).

So to differenciate them you should use `length`:

```
length(t)
length(p)
```