# R - Data Frame is a list of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

## Question

1. Is a data frame in R is a list (list is, in my understanding, a sequence of objects) of columns?
2. What is the design decision in R to have made a data frame a column-oriented (not row-oriented) structure?
3. Any reference to related design document or article of data structure design would be appreciated.

I am just used to row-as-a-unit/record and would like to know why it is column oriented. Or if I misunderstood something, kindly suggest.

### Background

I had thought a dataframe was a sequence of row, such as (Ozone, Solar.R, Wind, Temp, Month, Day).

```
> c ## data frame created from read.csv()
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
7    23     299  8.6   65     5   7
8    19      99 13.8   59     5   8

> typeof(c)
[1] "list"
```

However when lapply() is applied against c to show each list element, it was a column.

```
> lapply(c, function(arg){ return(arg) })
$Ozone
[1] 41 36 12 18 23 19
$Solar.R
[1] 190 118 149 313 299  99
$Wind
[1]  7.4  8.0 12.6 11.5  8.6 13.8
$Temp
[1] 67 72 74 62 65 59
$Month
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5
$Day
[1] 1 2 3 4 7 8
```

Whereas I had expected was

```
[1]    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
[1]    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
…
```

Comment: Use `apply(c,2, function(arg){ return(arg) })` instead. And `c` is a data.frame (see `class(c)`). And don't use `c` as a variable name. And this might help: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/171535.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/r-types-and-classes-of-variables

Comment: Vectors have a single mode, so each row cannot be a vector.  But each column can be a vector.

Comment: @Pascal The downside of using `c` as an object name is no longer applicable.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg  Is it a good reason to use it?

Comment: It used to cause trouble if you did it.  It now causes no ill-effects, so there is no reason to avoid it.

Comment: I still avoid the use of `c`, `df`, `T`, `F` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) *Is a data frame in R a list of columns?*

Yes.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("the", "quick"), b=c("brown", "fox"), c=1:2)
is.list(df)        # -> TRUE
attr(df, "name")   # -> [1] "a" "b" "c"
df[[1]][2]         # -> "quick"
```

2) *What is the design decision in R to have made a data frame a column-oriented (not row-oriented) structure?*

A data.frame is a list of column **vectors**.

```
is.atomic(df[[1]])     # -> TRUE
mode(df[[1]])          # -> [1] "character"
mode(df[[3]])          # -> [1] "numeric"
```

Vectors can only store one kind of object. A "row-oriented" data.frame would demand data frames be composed of lists instead. Now imagine what the performance of an operation like

```
df[[1]][20000]
```

would be in a list-based data frame keeping in mind that random access is O(1) for vectors and O(n) for lists.

3) *Any reference to related design document or article of data structure design would be appreciated.*

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#data-frames