# How to know if the data is a list or data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

How do I know if my data in R is a list or a data.frame?

If I use `typeof(x)` it says list, if I use `class(x)` it says data.frame?

Comment: `data.frame` is a special kind of `list`. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/r-types-and-classes-of-variables) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/438/data-frames/1458/create-an-empty-data-frame#t=201607230816043614997).

Answer (score 39):

To clarify a possible misunderstanding given the title of your question, a `data.frame` is also a list.

```r
is.list(data.frame())   # TRUE
```

However, you can use `inherits()` to see if an object is a `list` or `data.frame`

```r
inherits(data.frame(), "data.frame")  # TRUE
inherits(list(), "data.frame")        # FALSE
    
inherits(data.frame(), "list")        # FALSE
inherits(list(), "list")              # TRUE
```

---

Or alternatively, `methods::is()`, but is ever-so-slightly slower.

```r
is(data.frame(), "data.frame")  # TRUE
is(list(), "data.frame")        # FALSE

is(data.frame(), "list")        # FALSE
is(list(), "list")              # TRUE
```

From `?is` help page:

> Although inherits is defined for S3 classes, it has been modified so that the result returned is nearly always equivalent to is, both for S4 and non-S4 objects. Since it is implemented in C, it is somewhat faster.