# Normalizing a dataframe - Error : non-numeric argument to binary - R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, normalize

I went through similar questions but I still could not sort my problem out. Anyway, 
I have a data-frame (size:36*42) that contains numbers while in the last row (36'th row) it has the dates for each column.
I wanted to normalize the columns of this data-frame (the whole data-frame except the last row) using the following function:

```
normalize<-function(x){return((x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))/(max(x, na.rm=TRUE)-min(x, na.rm=TRUE)))}
```

but I always get this error:

```
Error in x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The thing that I have tried

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df[c(1:nrow(df)-1),], normalize))
```

BTW, when I check the `typeof(df)` it shows that the `df` is a `list` but when I check it using `is.list(df)->TRUE` and also `is.data.frame(df)->TRUE`, which it makes me confuse.

Thanks

Comment: You have some factors or characters in there. Try `sapply(df,class)`. You should provide sample data with `dput`. Did you type this as is `is.list(df)->TRUE`?

Comment: regarding your question about your `data.frame` having a `list` type, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/types-and-classes-of-variables) post.

Comment: @NelsonGon, Yes

Comment: @NelsonGon, "Did you type this as is is.list(df)->TRUE?", Yes

Comment: Also, I am trying to extract the data to upload it here

Comment: If you just want to calculate on the `numeric`s, maybe simply do: `normalize<-function(x){
  x<-Filter(is.numeric,x)
  return( (x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE)) / (max(x, na.rm=TRUE)-min(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with variable class.  Check the class - class( mtcars$mpg ) .  This function will convert your cols to numeric

```
normalize<-function(x){

x <- as.numeric( as.character( x ))

y <- (x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))/
    (max(x, na.rm=TRUE)-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))

return(y)

}
```

It works see:
    normalize( mtcars$mpg )
    normalize( as.character( mtcars$mpg ))

You can add to your dataframe

```
mtcars$newvar <- normalize( mtcars$mpg )
```

or do several cols

```
mtcars[ , 3:7]<- sapply( mtcars[ , 3:7], normalize )
```

Comment: Thanks @MatthewR. It is working but it removes the name of columns and rows. How should I deal with it?

Comment: mtcars$newvar <- normalize( mtcars$mpg )

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your `normalize` function through only numeric variables with `mutate_if` from `dplyr`.

```
 library(dplyr)

normalize<-function(x){
 return( (x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE)) / (max(x, na.rm=TRUE)-min(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
}

df %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, normalize)
```

Since you didn't provide a sample from your data, using `iris` dataset it would be something like:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, normalize)
```

and the output would be (first ten rows):

```
#Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1     0.22222222  0.62500000   0.06779661  0.04166667     setosa
#2     0.16666667  0.41666667   0.06779661  0.04166667     setosa
#3     0.11111111  0.50000000   0.05084746  0.04166667     setosa
#4     0.08333333  0.45833333   0.08474576  0.04166667     setosa
#5     0.19444444  0.66666667   0.06779661  0.04166667     setosa
#6     0.30555556  0.79166667   0.11864407  0.12500000     setosa
#7     0.08333333  0.58333333   0.06779661  0.08333333     setosa
#8     0.19444444  0.58333333   0.08474576  0.04166667     setosa
#9     0.02777778  0.37500000   0.06779661  0.04166667     setosa
#10    0.16666667  0.45833333   0.08474576  0.00000000     setosa
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your answer works if we do not have columns with the same name.

Comment: This should work on `data.frame`. I'd recommend not using same name on different variables...