# Changing the Type of a Variable When Assigning Multiple Classes

Tags: r, type-conversion

I am dealing with some S3 methods in R. I created a class system for them and everything works fine. However, sometimes different types of objects are problematic and I stumbled across the fact that types only change when a single class is assigned, not multiple classes or let alone non-base classes.

How can I enforce to change the type along with the class? Preferably automatically/at once to safe computation time.

```
x <- 1L
class(x)
#> [1] "integer"
typeof(x)
#> [1] "integer"

# assigning one class chages the type accordingly
class(x) <- "character"
class(x)
#> [1] "character"
typeof(x)
#> [1] "character"

# assigning multiple classes does not change the type
x <- 1L
class(x) <- c("character", "foo")
class(x)
#> [1] "character" "foo"
typeof(x) # should be character
#> [1] "integer"

# actual goal would be to change the type by the first 
# known class - type tandem
x <- 1L
class(x) <- c("foo", "character")
class(x)
#> [1] "foo"       "character"
typeof(x) # should be character
#> [1] "integer"
```

Answer (score 1):

Enforcing a change is better done via `as.character` or any other `as.xxx` or `xxx` function. Just changing the class is asking for problems. Also the `as.xxx` or `xxx` will return an error if something is not working as expected. Changing classes does not give any errors and might fail your code.

E.g. a data.frame is of class data.frame, but typeof is a list. Changing the class of a list to class data.frame does not change it correctly into a data.frame. But it doesn't give an error if you change a list via class into a data.frame, but the results might not be what you want.

Example:

```
my_list <- list(a = c(letters[1:4]),
                b = c(letters[5:7]))

# error
as.data.frame(my_list)

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
                      arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3

# wrong results                    
class(my_list) <- "data.frame"
is.data.frame(my_list)
TRUE
my_list
[1] a b
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Adding your own classes are very handy as you can use this as checks inside functions and as checks on outputs.

For more information I suggest reading the following posts about the difference between class and typeof and the links inside them to the R manuals:

[A comprehensive survey of the types of things in R; 'mode' and 'class' and 'typeof' are insufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855589/a-comprehensive-survey-of-the-types-of-things-in-r-mode-and-class-and-type)

[Types and classes of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/types-and-classes-of-variables)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/mode-class-and-type-of-r-objects