# R: Comparing list with grouped values in dataframe; questions about data types

Tags: r, list, dplyr, types

I'm trying to make booleans for the dataframe `testdf` where when grouped by `id`, the boolean indicates whether everything in the vector `values` exists in that id's values.

I believe that ultimately this is a question about the different vector/list data types in R, which I still don't understand.

The vector `values` comes from the second column in `lookup`. R says it's a vector but not a list (should I do `as.list(lookup$values)` instead)?

```
testdf <- data.frame(id = c('a','a','a','b','b'),
                     value = c(1,2,3,1,2))

lookup <- data.frame(col1 = c('x','y','z'),
                     values = c(1,2,3))

values <- lookup$values
```

These produce:

```
> testdf
  id value
1  a     1
2  a     2
3  a     3
4  b     1
5  b     2

> lookup
  col1 values
1    x      1
2    y      2
3    z      3

> values
[1] 1 2 3
```

And my intended result would look like this. `values_bool` is TRUE for an `id` where all elements in `values` exist in `value_list`. Note that I formatted the lists in a generic way.

```
testdf
  id value_list values_bool
1  a    [1,2,3]        TRUE
2  b      [1,2]       FALSE
```

This [page](https://dcl-prog.stanford.edu/list-columns.html) includes some more information on the creation and use of list columns in R, although it doesn't explain the difference in data types generated within each list.

For example, a cell in the list column created by `nest()` looks like this:
`asia       <tibble [59 × 1]>`

and a cell in the list column created by `summarize()` and `list()` looks like this:
`asia       <chr [59]>`

I tried to create list columns using two methods from that page in my code:

```
version1 <- testdf %>%
  # Make column listing values for each id
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(value_list = list(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

version2 <- testdf %>%
  # Nest values into list
  nest(value_list = value)
```

If you run this you can see they produce different list types.

```
> version1
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  id    value_list
  <chr> <list>    
1 a     <dbl [3]> 
2 b     <dbl [2]> 

> version2
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  id    value_list      
  <chr> <list>          
1 a     <tibble [3 × 1]>
2 b     <tibble [2 × 1]>
```

And when I try to add this line at the end of each, the output gives all False even though one should be True.

```
  # Mark whether all values exist in value_list for each id 
  mutate(values_bool = values %in% value_list)
```

So what's going on with the dataframe list data types when grouping `value` from `testdf` and selecting `values` from `lookup`?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You may want to loop over the `list` i.e. `version2 %>% mutate(values_bool = map(value_list, ~ values %in% .x$value))` or `version1 %>% mutate(values_bool = map(value_list, ~ values %in% .x))`

Comment: @akrun thanks for your reply! That gives a list like `c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)` for each `values_bool`, but how do I turn it into a single boolean checking if it's all true? The function `all()` throws an error, and checking with `!(FALSE %in% ... )` doesn't work.

Comment: You can wrap with `all` i.e. `version2 %>% mutate(values_bool = map_lgl(value_list, ~ all(values %in% .x$value, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@akrun answered this in the comments, but I love this question, which is really a deep inquiry into R data structures and functional programming, so I'm going to answer it in a longer form here and arrive at the same answer.

First the minimal reproducible problem setup (I simplify `version1` and `version2` to `v1` and `v2`):

```
library(tidyverse)

testdf <- data.frame(id = c('a','a','a','b','b'),
                     value = c(1,2,3,1,2))

lookup <- data.frame(col1 = c('x','y','z'),
                     values = c(1,2,3))

values <- lookup$values


v1 <- testdf %>%
  # Make column listing values for each id
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(value_list = list(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

v2 <- testdf %>%
  # Nest values into list
  nest(value_list = value)
```

In `v1` and `v2`, we create a `value_list` column that is a nested **list**. The list contents differ (you can tell by the reported dimensions in the OP).

- `v1$value_list` is a nested **atomic vector**
- `v2$value_list` is a nested **data.frame**

This is because `list()` -- when passed an **atomic vector** -- stores that atomic vector as an atomic vector, but `nest()` when passed an atomic vector, stores this as a `data.frame`. Why? Because `nest()` comes from the *functional programming* paradigm where we use `map()` (type-safe next gen `lapply()`) functions to operate on `data.frame` objects and importantly, **return** `data.frame` objects.

Okay, now let's start walking through the solution. It helps to understand how R represents the data types in `v1` and `v2`.

We begin with `v1`. calling `list()` on an atomic vector results in a 1D atomic vector. We can pull it out and examine it:

*Note that throughout the post I only include code. C/P and run interactively to see output*

```
v1                         # a dataframe
v1$value_list              # a column, which is itself a list (see below)
class(v1$value_list)       # verify this is a list
v1$value_list[[1]]         # b/c it's a list, use [[ notation to pull element 1
class(v1$value_list[[1]])  # it's an atomic vector - "numeric" = integer or double
typeof(v1$value_list[[1]]) # typeof() to show it's double
typeof(1L)                 # as opposed to a strict integer type
length(v1$value_list[[1]]) # atomic vectors have property length
```

Now we examine `v2`:

```
v2                         # a dataframe
v2$value_list              # a column-which is itself a list, see below
class(v2$value_list)       # verify this is a list
v2$value_list[[1]]         # b/c it's a list, use [[ notation to pull element 1
class(v2$value_list[[1]])  # it's a data.frame, NOT an atomic vector!
typeof(v2$value_list[[1]]) # typeof() to show a dataframe is a just special list
dim(v2$value_list[[1]])    # dataframes have property dim
length(v2$value_list[[1]]) # dataframes also have property length, which is ncol()
```

With that background on object types, let's move to the problem posed in the OP.

> And when I try to add this line at the end of each, the output gives all False even though one should be True.
>
> ```
> # Mark whether all values exist in value_list for each id 
> mutate(values_bool = values %in% value_list)
> ```

Essentially, we want to test if all `values` occur in `v1$value_list` or `v2$value_list`. The expected result is `TRUE`, and then `FALSE`, for grouping variables `a` and `b` respectively. First, we do this the long way, and then we build to a functional programming solution.

```
# exhaustive approach for list 1 with atomic vectors
values %in% v1$value_list[[1]]       # all values present
all(values %in% v1$value_list[[1]])  # returns TRUE as expected

# exhaustive approach for list 2 with atomic vectors
values %in% v1$value_list[[2]]       # one value missing
all(values %in% v1$value_list[[2]])  # returns FALSE as expected

# now the functional programming solution without indexing. Notes on syntax:
#   - Pass a list (or a vector) as the first argument.
#   - Use ~ to indicate the start of the function to apply across the list
#   - Use .x as a placehold within the function for the ith list element. Think: concise for-loop
map(v1$value_list, ~all(values %in% .x)) # returns c(TRUE, FALSE)

# Two solutions: because we want to output a vector we can unlist(), or 
# use map_lgl() which only returns a boolean and fails if the result is NOT bool
unlist(map(v1$value_list, ~all(values %in% .x))) # returns c(TRUE, FALSE)
map_lgl(v1$value_list, ~all(values %in% .x))     # returns c(TRUE, FALSE)
 
# now the functional programming solution in a pipe (put it all together):
v1 %>% 
  mutate(values_bool = map_lgl(value_list, ~all(values %in% .x)))

# we can do the same with v2, but we need to convert the dataframe to a vector
# so that it works with all() -- this is a bit tedious and verbose, because we 
# used nest() which is designed to work with nested dataframes, but we ultimately 
# want to use all() which takes vectors, so there was no need to nest() in the first
# place. For examples of how to use the power of nest(): 
# https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#creating-list-columns
v2 %>% 
  mutate(values_bool = map_lgl(value_list, ~all(values %in% .x$value)))
```

#### Additional Resources:

- [essential reading on vectors](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you for answering the 'why' of my question! These details are what I wasn't getting from just looking at other examples or reading the documentation without context. For example, I wouldn't have thought to pay attention to the differences between `class` and `typeof`, especially for the elements of `v2$value_list`. That `typeof(v2$value_list[[1]])` is `list` was surprising. Followup q, if `v1$value_list[[1]]` is an atomic vector, why is `typeof(v1$value_list[[1]])` double instead of list?

Comment: Thanks! I hope that was helpful. For more on `class()`, `typeof()`, & `mode()` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/types-and-classes-of-variables) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855589/a-comprehensive-survey-of-the-types-of-things-in-r-mode-and-class-and-type). In a nutshell, `class()` tells R what methods the object inherits, and `typeof()` is the data structure in memory. In practice, `class` is typically the most useful fr debugging because functions expect a class (e.g., a vector does not have `nrow()` but data.frame does). I rarely use `typeof` or `mode`