# Why the typeof() result won't change after converting a list to a data frame

Tags: r

I tried several methods to convert my list to data frame. But the result of typeof() is always "list". How can I change the type?

```
`my_nested_list <- list(id=list(1,2,3,4,5),
                   name=list('sai','ram','hari','deepak','sahithi'),
                   gender=list('m','m','m','m','f'))
df <- dplyr::as_tibble(my_nested_list)
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_nested_list))
df <- plyr::ldply(my_nested_list, data.frame)
typeof(df)`
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/types-and-classes-of-variables

Comment: Also, to change it into a data frame, you can use `data.frame(lapply(my_nested_list, unlist))`.